# How to rotate secret_key_base without losing sessions or ActionText attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

As part of a broader key rotation initiative, I want to rotate `secret_key_base` in a Rails 6.1.7 application. I've found https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#rotating-encrypted-and-signed-cookies-configurations, which points to https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.7/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html#class-ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor-label-Rotating+keys, but I don't understand how to put that into action. Specifically, we would like to avoid invalidating all sessions, but we absolutely can't lose our ActionText attachments.

I'm expecting something simple like what is described in https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/how-to-rotate-secrek-key-base-without-breaking-activestorage-actiontext-attachments/80865, in which we would get a verifier that has already been created and call `rotate(old_key_base)` on it.

There is this from the Rails guide referenced above for changing cookies:

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_rotations.tap do |cookies|
  cookies.rotate :signed, digest: "SHA1"
end
```

But `rotate` appears to take a secret, not `secret_key_base`.

I'm also having trouble testing session maintenance because changing `secret_key_base` in development doesn't affect sessions in development (from the Rails guide: "In test and development applications get a secret_key_base derived from the app name."), but changing `secret_key_base` *does* invalidate my ActionText attachments (and, what is more mysterious, changing the `secret_key_base` back to the original value does *not* fix the invalidated ActionText attachments).